# How to identify memory leak with slowly eating up memory

Tags: macos, memory-leaks

I wrote a small app which calls every few seconds for checking folders. I run this app for appr. one week.  Now I saw that it had occupied 32 GB of my physical 8 GB RAM. So system forced me to stop it.
So it seems that very slowly the app eats up memory. I tried Instruments. With activity monitor the only slowly growing process is "DTServiceHub". Is this something I have to watch at?
For debugging I write some information with print to standard output. Is this information dropped, because app is Cocoa app or stored somewhere till termination of the app? In this case I have to remove all these print-Statements.

Some code for looping:

```
func startUpdating() {
    running = true
    timeInterval = 5
    run.isEnabled = false

    setTimer()
}

func setTimer() {
    timer = Timer(timeInterval: timeInterval, target: self, selector: #selector(ViewController.update), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
    RunLoop.current.add(timer, forMode: RunLoopMode.commonModes)
}

    func update() {
        writeLOG("update -Start-", level: 0x2)
...
        setTimer()
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried the Allocations instrument and checking the memory between snapshots?

Comment: @matt: First I tested it with some stuff to do, then I left it running doing nothing but waiting (bc. there were no jobs to do). Then after one week it reached the limit. => It must depend on the simple looping without doing any special tasks.

Comment: @Abizern: Yes, but I could not identify where to go. "All heap Allocations" grows up slowly by some KB every second. It is growing even if app is waiting with "Thread.sleep".

Comment: I added the central loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several problems with your code. You should **not** create a Timer and then add it to a run loop every time you set it, because the run loop will retain that Timer and will never release it. Even worse is when you try to do that every time you update. Just create the timer once. If you don't need it anymore you have to invalidate it to remove it from the run loop and allow its release. If you need to adjust it just set the next fire date.

Here is an example that was tested in a playground:

```
import Cocoa

class MyTimer
{
    var fireTime = 10.0
    var timer:Timer

    init()
    {
        self.timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: fireTime, target: self, selector: #selector(update), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }

    deinit
    {
         // it will remove the timer from the run loop and it will enable its release            
         timer.invalidate()
    }

    @objc func update()
    {
        print("update")
        let calendar = Calendar.current
        let date = Date()

        if let nextFireDate = calendar.date(byAdding: .second, value: Int(fireTime), to: date)
        {
            print(date)
            timer.fireDate = nextFireDate
        }
    }
}

let timer = MyTimer()

CFRunLoopRun()
```

Comment: I found this snippets in an example. How should I add the new created timer? I need to update the date for next firing. How to set it? "timer.timeInterval" is a read only property.

Comment: Ok, I read it, but I didn't get it for changing something of my existing code. I get the error that even if "timer.timeInterval" is defined as var, it is read only. So I think I have to recreate each timer again with new interval. So it would be great if you can offer some optimized code.

Comment: Thank you very much. "fireDate"! I will try it.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your app loops forever and thus never drains the auto release pool. You should never write an app like that. If you need to check something periodically, use an NSTimer. If you need to hear about changes in a folder, use NSWorkspace or kqueue or similar. In other words, use callbacks. Never just loop.

Comment: Thank you. I will now search for NSTimer (hope it is Swift 3.0 compatible).

Comment: Yes. This works. I used Timer instead of NSTimer. Now I have to run it for some days to check if problem is now resolved.

Comment: Issue is the same: Even when waiting for Timer, All heap allocation increments in small KB steps! (I updated the code above!)